# PHP: Sending variables to another page but are undefined (variables are in phpinfo() )

Tags: php, variables, action

I have a tiny issue where sending variables to another page yields undefined variables.

Page 1:

```
    <form name= "updateProfiel" method="POST" action="index.php?page=updateProfiel">
    <input required type="text" name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $result['voornaam']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="text" name="achternaam" value="<?php echo $result['achternaam']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="text" name="adres" value="<?php echo $result['adres']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $result['postcode']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="text" name="woonplaats" value="<?php echo $result['woonplaats']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $result['email']; ?>"/>
    <input required type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value=" Update " />
    <a href="index.php?page=welkom">Annuleren</a>
</form>
```

Page 2:
        (page name is updateProfiel.php)

```
    $voornaam = htmlspecialchars($_POST["voornaam"]);
    $achternaam = htmlspecialchars($_POST["achternaam"]);
    $adres = htmlspecialchars($_POST["adres"]);
    $postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST["postcode"]);
    $woonplaats = htmlspecialchars($_POST["woonplaats"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`
```

I used `phpinfo();` to see if the variables got sent from page 1 to page 2, and they are there:

[The phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwPos.png)

But if I try to set them as variables and use them they're undefined!..
Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: What is your error log saying?

Comment: Maybe post directly to `updateProfiel.php` ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `phpinfo()` to debug your variables, use `var_dump($_POST);` instead. I'd guess because you are POSTing to index.php you are somehow redirecting and your $_POST vars are being thrown away.

Comment: @Xatenev the var_dump seems to be empty.. `Array(0) {}` is all I get.

Comment: @CarlovanEeckhoven So that means your variables are not there. Are you redirecting inbetween? From index.php or something?

Comment: @AdamA `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: voornaam in <b>` is the only thing I'm getting (times 8, one for every item)

Comment: @Xatenev Not that I know of. The action is `action="index.php?page=updateProfiel"` with a `method="POST"`

Comment: @CarlovanEeckhoven Change the action to updateProfiel.php directly. If that works it means your index.php does something weird (like redirecting)

Comment: @Xatenev I tried that just now. But then the page cannot be found anymore. I'll try one more thing

EDIT:

pages/updateProfiel  nor updateProfiel.php work. The page cannot be found.

Comment: @CarlovanEeckhoven Then find out where your page actually is.

Comment: `find -iname 'updateProfiel.php'`

Comment: Hi Carlo, @Xateven is more than right, you are messing at index.php?page= because ther est of the code is more than ok. I'd suggest to use if(isset($_POST["voornaam"])) ref. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php before using a variable and you can catch the error and respond accordingly

Comment: @oetoni Hi Oetoni, not to blame others. But that piece of code is wrong the studybook I’m using. Telling me to make the second page. So I have no idea how to make it work, then. But I’ll try the ‘find -iname’ in a bit when im back home. Thanks all for up to now!

Comment: @Xateven I cleared up my 'page 2' a bit, if I do a var_dump it shows the array now! BUT.. It still says they're undefined.

Let me clearify: The array is there in the console. But if I look at the page-source it's not there. So, never mind that, I guess.

Comment: @Xatenev The undefined variables were not undefined. The source-page just said so. The issue was with the SQL-query... My bad. Thanks for all your help, though!! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very embarassing. 
The undefined variables are actually not undefined. The source-page just says so.

The issue was somewhere else :')... Thanks for everyone's help!

Ps: The issue was the fact that a piece of SQL-query for the database was missing two brackets.. Yay.